# Целочисленная константа в классе - enum или static const?

Tags: c++, c++-faq

Есть два способа сделать константное значение в классе:

Использовать перечисление:

```
class C {
  enum { X = 42; }
};
```

Или статический член класса:

```
class C {
  static const auto X = 42;
};
```

Какой способ предпочтительнее? Какие могут быть подводные камни?

Comment: Имеет смысл указать, что речь только об интегральных типах. Иначе, `enum` вообще не вариант.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Статический член класса позволяет использовать вывод типов:

```
static const auto X = 1ul;
```

Для `enum` тип надо писать самому (если он не `int`):

```
enum { X = 1 };
enum : unsigned long { Y = 1 };
```

Получается что статический член класса выглядит предпочтительнее, к тому же он семантически является константой, а перечисление больше рассчитано на "перечисление" нескольких значений.

### Подводные камни

Если мы попробуем скомпилировать следующий код

```
struct C {
    static const auto X = 1;
};

int f(const int& arg) {
    return arg;
}

int main() {
    return f(C::X);
}
```

То мы [можем получить](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59a40200f5fa8c3b) ошибку линковки (при отключенном оптимизаторе):

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `C::X'
```

Оказывается, статические целочисленные константные члены классов не требуют отдельного определения только если они не ODR-использованы (odr-used). Мы берем ссылку на `C::X`, это делает ее *odr-used*, и значит мы должны добавить ее определение вне класса:

```
struct C {
    static const auto X = 1;
};

const int C::X; // В одном из .cpp файлов.
```

Термин "odr-used" определен в главе *"One definition rule [basic.def.odr]"* следующим образом:

> Переменная, чье имя использовано в потенциально вычисляемом контексте (т.е. не `sizeof` или `decltype`), является *odr-used*, за исключением случая когда она является объектом, который может быть использован в константном выражении, и к ней сразу же применяется преобразование из lvalue в rvalue.

В нашем случае `C::X` может быть использована в константном выражении, однако она является lvalue и передается в `f()` как ссылка на lvalue. Если мы добавим преобразование в rvalue, то отдельное определение `C::X` уже будет не нужно, и ошибка линковки пропадет:

```
f(static_cast<int>(C::X));  // явный каст
f(+C::X); // унарный плюс
```

Какой из этого можно сделать вывод?
Статические арифметические константные члены классов слишком удобны чтобы от них отказываться, и если вдруг появится ошибка линковки, то достаточно использовать унарный плюс чтобы ее починить.

Comment: Хм. Странно, что ошибка зависит от включённого оптимизатора. Вы уверены?

Comment: И правда. Хм. Вот не подумал бы.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужен ограниченный набор констант для определенного действия то в приоритете перечисление (enum) для примера приведу перичисление цвета:

```
enum color { 
  red;
  green;
  blue;
};
```

т.е. количество принимающих значений для цвета конечно. во всех остальных случаях нужно применять обычную константу